# Validate YAML file using Powershell/CMD in Azure pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to validate the YAML file in azure pipeline either via PowerShell or CMD, if the YAML file is invalid then it should fail the task.

Can you please suggest some inputs on how to achieve it.

Comment: Do you mean to `azure-pipelines.yml` file or another `.yml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like *Shayki Abramczyk* commented not sure if you want to `azure-pipelines.yml` file or another `.yml` file

### For `azure-pipelines.yml`

There is a server-side API for this :

POST to `dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_apis/pipelines/<pipelineId>/runs?api-version=5.1-preview` with a JSON body like this:

```
{
  "PreviewRun": true,
  "YamlOverride": "
# your new YAML here, optionally
"
}
```

The response will contain the rendered YAML. More details you could refer link here: [Expose YAML validation features as standalone tool](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/34)

### For other `.yml` file

You could either use a script in powershell task or some 3rd-party extension [Files Validator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=roshkovski.Files-Validator&ssr=false#overview) to handle this.

Comment: Yes, Files Validator, works like a charm, but we are not suppose to use due to some restrictions :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `powershell-yaml` module to validate YAML file as below:

```yaml
    steps:
    - pwsh: Install-Module powershell-yaml -Force
    - pwsh: |
        $content = Get-Content -Path stackoverflow\80-yaml\test.yaml -Raw
        $correct = true
        try {
          $obj = ConvertFrom-Yaml $content
          Write-Host $obj
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "An error occurred:"
            
            $correct = false
        }
        

        
        Write-Host $correct
```

But please remember about setting [$ErrorActionPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060042/powershell-try-block-not-working-on-vsts-build)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works but is it according to OpenAPI Specification standard ?

Comment: Difficult to say as this is implementation detail of powershell-yaml module. Can you consider upvoing my anser if it was useful for you?